# Add link on the top menu of the post table?

Tags: posts, admin, views, lists

Is there any way to add links on the top, as pictured below?

[image: Post list views]

Answer (score 4):

They are filtered via [the `views_[screen-id]` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L225). The `screen-id` of the edit post page is `edit-post`, so you can modify the links like this:

```
add_action( 'views_edit-post', 'wpse17484_views_edit_post' );
function wpse17484_views_edit_post( $views )
{
    $views['wpse17484'] = '<a href="my-url">My action</a>';
    return $views;
}
```

You can see the code that generates the post views in [`WP_Posts_List_Table::get_views()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L129).